# Is there way to create business month where quantity is zero

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with various contracts numbers with business months and where quantity is not zero. I would like to achieve remaining business month of the year where quantities are zero. There are multiple contracts in the table.  As you can see the example 1

[image]

and desired outcome including records for 16110  I would like to have in example 2.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Generate full year-month values list in needed range in CTE (or using generator function if exists in DBMS) and join your table to it.

Comment: OUTER JOIN it...

Comment: BTW, are you using MySQL or Oracle?

Comment: PS. How to distinguish what row values (for contract, currency, etc.) from 5 source rows must be used for filling according columns for the months which are absent in source? I do not see any guarantee that these fields values are equal for all source rows (or prove is showing table's DDL with according constraint).

Comment: I am using PL SQL

Comment: PL/SQL is Oracle's procedural language. If you are just writing queries then you are using Oracle's SQL dialect and not PL/SQL.

Answer (score 2):

## Oracle

Use a partitioned outer join with a generated calendar:

```sql
SELECT t.contractid,
       c.month AS bm,
       t.sales_product_number,
       t.currency_tc,
       t.end_customer_no,
       COALESCE( t.billings_quantity, 0 ) AS billings_quantity
FROM   (
         SELECT TO_NUMBER(
                  TO_CHAR(
                    ADD_MONTHS( DATE '2018-01-01', LEVEL-1 ),
                    'YYYYMM'
                  )
                ) AS month
         FROM   DUAL
         CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 12
       ) c
       LEFT OUTER JOIN test_data t
       PARTITION BY ( contractid, sales_product_number, currency_tc, end_customer_no )
       ON ( t.bm = c.month );
```

So, for your test data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE test_data ( contractid, bm, sales_product_number, currency_tc, end_customer_no, billings_quantity ) AS
SELECT 15939, 201802, 'SP000095923', 'EUR', 400009, 60 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 15939, 201804, 'SP000095923', 'EUR', 400009, 60 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 15939, 201808, 'SP000095923', 'EUR', 400009, 40 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 15939, 201811, 'SP000095923', 'EUR', 400009, 60 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 15939, 201812, 'SP000095923', 'EUR', 400009, 60 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> CONTRACTID |     BM | SALES_PRODUCT_NUMBER | CURRENCY_TC | END_CUSTOMER_NO | BILLINGS_QUANTITY
> ---------: | -----: | :------------------- | :---------- | --------------: | ----------------:
>      15939 | 201801 | SP000095923          | EUR         |          400009 |                 0
>      15939 | 201802 | SP000095923          | EUR         |          400009 |                60
>      15939 | 201803 | SP000095923          | EUR         |          400009 |                 0
>      15939 | 201804 | SP000095923          | EUR         |          400009 |                60
>      15939 | 201805 | SP000095923          | EUR         |          400009 |                 0
>      15939 | 201806 | SP000095923          | EUR         |          400009 |                 0
>      15939 | 201807 | SP000095923          | EUR         |          400009 |                 0
>      15939 | 201808 | SP000095923          | EUR         |          400009 |                40
>      15939 | 201809 | SP000095923          | EUR         |          400009 |                 0
>      15939 | 201810 | SP000095923          | EUR         |          400009 |                 0
>      15939 | 201811 | SP000095923          | EUR         |          400009 |                60
>      15939 | 201812 | SP000095923          | EUR         |          400009 |                60
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=ab2e327d28502711e1d766d0e4b11d09)*

---

## Update

This will partition on year as well as the other columns:

```sql
WITH data ( contractid, year, month, sales_product_number, currency_tc, end_customer_no, billings_quantity ) AS (
  SELECT contractid,
         SUBSTR( bm, 1, 4 ),
         TO_NUMBER( SUBSTR( bm, 5, 2 ) ),
         sales_product_number,
         currency_tc,
         end_customer_no,
         billings_quantity
  FROM   test_data
)
SELECT t.contractid,
       TO_NUMBER( t.year || TO_CHAR( c.month, 'FM00') ) AS bm,
       t.sales_product_number,
       t.currency_tc,
       t.end_customer_no,
       COALESCE( t.billings_quantity, 0 ) AS billings_quantity
FROM   (
         SELECT LEVEL AS month
         FROM   DUAL
         CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 12
       ) c
       LEFT OUTER JOIN data t
       PARTITION BY ( contractid, year, sales_product_number, currency_tc, end_customer_no )
       ON ( t.month = c.month );
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=50bbea1b64f58715c4a41b23d3027e42)*

Comment: Thanks, is there any possible way to have a dynamic business month. Currently you have hard coded 2018-01-01 but there are lot of other contracts which have different business months.

Comment: Basically every contract to be reported on calendar month (jan-Dec) and show quantity 0 where there are no values.

Comment: @N.Sood - DATE '2018-01-01' is just an anchor point for the start of the generated range. Why not try it? You'll find you get all the months.

Comment: @N.Sood Your question only contains data from one year and for one contract and, as such, I've only answered the question that you've asked. If you want an answer that is more relevant to your expanded problem then you'll need to [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63826587/edit) the question be a [MRE] including all the relevant information such as data for multiple contracts and the method with which the minimum and maximum bounds of the calendar should be calculated. Preferably with the data as text (which can be copy/pasted) and not images (which we can't).

Comment: My apologies, I am new to this and just wanted to give a small example. I think you can imagine having multiple contracts with different time frames. How would it be possible to achieve the desired results with dynamic year months with results showing 0 where there is no quantity. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, it works. But I have a another challenge where:                                   
 CREATE TABLE test_data_c ( contractid,valid_from,valid_to, sales_product_number, currency_tc, end_customer_no, contract_quantity ) AS
SELECT 15939, 201801,  201812, 'SP000095923', 'EUR', 400009, 17000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 16000, 201804,  201809, 'SP000095333', 'USD', 400010, 23000 FROM DUAL ;

Comment: @N.Sood Please [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) rather than trying to expand the scope of this one. You can always include code and/or a link back to this question in your new question.

Comment: MT0: I have created a new post. I will be thankful to you for your help. Can you also additionally let me know best way to learn SQL. Is there any nice training, courses I can do to enhance my skills. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63848513/is-there-a-way-to-show-date-range-or-date-from-date-to-in-a-new-field-with-yyy

Comment: If possible give your feedback as the one i have is little bad for query performance. I like your code.