# Is there a way to show date range or date_from & date_to in a new field with YYYYMM as a BM

Tags: sql, oracle, common-table-expression

I have a table of contracts as shown below:

```
CREATE TABLE test_data_c ( contractid,valid_from,valid_to, year_month, 
    sales_product_number, currency_tc, end_customer_no, contract_quantity ) AS
    SELECT 15939, 201801,  201812,'201801-201812', 'SP000095923', 'EUR', 400009, 17000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 16000, 201806,  201809,'201806-201809', 'SP000095333', 'USD', 400010, 23000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 17000, 201810,  201903,'201810-201903', 'SP000095999', 'EUR', 400050, 20000 FROM DUAL ;
```

I would like to get the outcome as shown in the example where a new field with YYYYMM is created to show the date range as BM.
[image]

example 3. [image]

Comment: The code looks more like Oracle so I removed the MySQL tag.

Comment: Hint: Recursive Query

Answer (score 1):

One way is using a Recursive Query:

```
with cte (BM, contractid,valid_from,valid_to, year_month) as
  ( select substr(year_month, 1, 6) as BM
       ,contractid,valid_from,valid_to, year_month
    from test_data_c t
    union all
    select to_char(add_months(to_date(BM, 'YYYYMM'), 1), 'YYYYMM')
       ,contractid,valid_from,valid_to, year_month
    from cte 
    where cte.BM < substr(year_month, 8, 6) 
  )
select * 
from cte
order by 2,1
```

See [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=ab2ea559c71222b1f3f73d01a3676453)

Comment: This is a better answer anyway, too lazy to fix my funky old connect by query.

Answer (score 0):

You can use such a query with hierarchical row generation format in which years are derived from a subquery, and months form the other one :

```
WITH mon AS
(
 SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTR(year_month, 1, 6) + level - 1 as bm, t.*
   FROM test_data_c t
CONNECT BY level <= SUBSTR(year_month, -6) - SUBSTR(year_month, 1, 6) + 1
    AND PRIOR SYS_GUID() IS NOT NULL
    AND PRIOR contractid = contractid
), yr AS
(
 SELECT DISTINCT contractid, SUBSTR(year_month, -4) + 1 AS yr
   FROM test_data_c t
CONNECT BY level <= SUBSTR(year_month, -4) + 1
    AND PRIOR SYS_GUID() IS NOT NULL
    AND PRIOR contractid = contractid
)
SELECT mon.*
  FROM mon
  JOIN yr
    ON yr.contractid = mon.contractid
 WHERE SUBSTR(bm,-2) BETWEEN '01' AND '12'   
 ORDER BY mon.contractid, mon.bm
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=97fa37b1066003da9cbc2240a4d8be73)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks but query performance is really bad on actual table.

Comment: You're welcome @N.Sood . How many rows are there within the table ..?

Comment: Hi, In the real table there are may be 1 million rows. When i runt the query it takes ages to run and still I do not see any results.

Comment: @N.Sood I suppose you'll run this query in order to create a new table once, so you'll wait once. You'll populate new table by adding a new column value for `bm` during the insertion, and get rid of the current table, don't you ..?

Comment: I was thinking to just run the query on top of my existing table not sure if it is necessary to create a new table and load it.